# Calculate the differences between one row and the rest of the data per group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I have a `data.table` with three `id` groups. The first group (`batch1`) has fixed `dx` and varied `dy`. The 2nd group (`batch1`) and 3rd group (`batch2`) have varied `dx` and fixed `dy`.

I want to calculate the differences between the row `id` ended in `1` and the other rows ended in `2`, `3`, etc. for each group.

How do I go about doing this? I'm open to `base`, `dplyr` or `data.table` solutions.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(
  id = as.factor(c("batch1_dx0.0_dy-2.1_4", "batch1_dx0.0_dy0.155_3",
                   "batch1_dx0.0_dy1.23_2", "batch1_dx0.0_dy1_1", 
                   "batch1_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2", "batch1_dx0_dy1.0_1",
                   "batch1_dx1.321_dy1.0_3", "batch1_dx4.12_dy1.0_4",
                   "batch2_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2", "batch2_dx0_dy1.0_1",
                   "batch2_dx1.321_dy1.0_3", "batch2_dx4.12_dy1.0_4")),
  val1 = c(6, 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 1),
  val2 = c(6, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 8, 9),
  val3 = c(6, 3, 3, 0, 4, 2, 4, 1, 5, 7, 1))

                        id val1 val2 val3
 1:  batch1_dx0.0_dy-2.1_4    6    6    6
 2: batch1_dx0.0_dy0.155_3    2    4    3
 3:  batch1_dx0.0_dy1.23_2    2    2    3
 4:     batch1_dx0.0_dy1_1    0    1    0
 5:  batch1_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2    3    1    4
 6:     batch1_dx0_dy1.0_1    1    1    2
 7: batch1_dx1.321_dy1.0_3    3    5    4
 8:  batch1_dx4.12_dy1.0_4    3    3    1
 9:  batch2_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2    4    2    5
10:     batch2_dx0_dy1.0_1    5    8    7
11: batch2_dx1.321_dy1.0_3    1    9    1
12:  batch2_dx4.12_dy1.0_4    6    6    6
```

Expected output

```
    id  val1    val2    val3    dval1   dval2   dval3
batch1_dx0.0_dy-2.1_4   6   6   6   6   5   6
batch1_dx0.0_dy0.155_3  2   4   3   2   3   3
batch1_dx0.0_dy1.23_2   2   2   3   2   1   3
batch1_dx0.0_dy1_1  0   1   0   0   0   0
batch1_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2   3   1   4   2   0   2
batch1_dx0_dy1.0_1  1   1   2   0   0   0
batch1_dx1.321_dy1.0_3  3   5   4   2   4   2
batch1_dx4.12_dy1.0_4   3   3   1   2   2   -1
batch2_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2   4   2   5   -1  -6  -2
batch2_dx0_dy1.0_1  5   8   7   0   0   0
batch2_dx1.321_dy1.0_3  1   9   1   -4  1   -6
batch2_dx4.12_dy1.0_4   6   6   6   1   -2  -1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first extract the last numeric part from each `id`. (`ind`). We then create groups for every 4th row and for every column that `starts_with` "val" we subtract it's value from the value with 1 in the `ind` column.

```
library(dplyr)

 dt %>%
   mutate(ind = sub(".*_(\\d+$)", "\\1", id)) %>%
   group_by(group = gl(n()/4, 4)) %>%
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with("val")), list(d = ~(. - .[ind == 1]))) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-group, -ind)



#     id                     val1  val2  val3 val1_d val2_d val3_d
#    <fct>                  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 batch1_dx0.0_dy-2.1_4      6     6     6      6      5      6
# 2 batch1_dx0.0_dy0.155_3     2     4     3      2      3      3
# 3 batch1_dx0.0_dy1.23_2      2     2     3      2      1      3
# 4 batch1_dx0.0_dy1_1         0     1     0      0      0      0
# 5 batch1_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2      3     1     4      2      0      2
# 6 batch1_dx0_dy1.0_1         1     1     2      0      0      0
# 7 batch1_dx1.321_dy1.0_3     3     5     4      2      4      2
# 8 batch1_dx4.12_dy1.0_4      3     3     1      2      2     -1
# 9 batch2_dx-0.8_dy1.0_2      4     2     5     -1     -6     -2
#10 batch2_dx0_dy1.0_1         5     8     7      0      0      0
#11 batch2_dx1.321_dy1.0_3     1     9     1     -4      1     -6
#12 batch2_dx4.12_dy1.0_4      6     6     6      1     -2     -1
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak for helping me again. Your results at line 7 & 8 didn't match with my hand calculations. The group was wrong I believe

Comment: @ReeseWithouterspoon oops..yes. I used a different logic for creation of groups. How are groups identified? When one group starts and ends?

Comment: Each group has 4 rows. Either `dx` or `dy` was changed but not both

Comment: can I consider every group would always have 4 rows? Or do I need to extract `dx` and `dy` values separately?

Comment: Yes the number of rows per group is known in advance which is 4

Comment: ok..I have updated the answer. Can you check if it works on your real data.

Comment: You are awesome!